# Round number up to a certain combination of given values

Tags: algorithm, rounding

I've been having a hard time solving this and also explaining it to people, but I will try: I have a float number and I want it rounded to the nearest combination of a few other given numbers.

I will now go straight into examples, otherwise I'm afraid I'll lose you:

Let's say our *numbers to round up to* are: 190, 290, 540, 1000

I'll provide some examples of given numbers and expected results just to make sure we are on the same page:

```
Given number: 54,6
Expected result: 190 (1x190)

Given number: 287,5
Expected result: 290 (1x290)

Given number: 575
Expected result: 580 (2x290) 

Given number: 1150 
Expected result: 1190 (1x1000 + 1x190)

Given number: 1955
Expected result: 2020 (1x1000 + 1x540 + 1x290 + 1x190)

Given number: 2875
Expected result: 3020 (2x1000 + 1x540 + 1x290 + 1x190)
```

So the point is to get the sum of values that equal or exceed the given number (and extract the one that exceeds the least?) I wrote a simple-minded function that somehow does what I want, but not exactly:

```js
function roundUpBasedOnPackaging(neededAmount, packagingIntegerArray) {

  console.log("We need to fill: " + neededAmount);

  var roundTo = 0;

  for (var len = packagingIntegerArray.length, i = len - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    var currentItemGrams = packagingIntegerArray[i];

    //console.log("we are at " + currentItemGrams);

    if (roundTo + currentItemGrams <= neededAmount) {
      console.log("-- add: " + currentItemGrams);
      roundTo += currentItemGrams;
      i = len; // try this again
    }
    // if last and we'r not filled yet
    else if (i == 0 && roundTo < neededAmount) {
      console.log("-- add to get over neededAmount: " + currentItemGrams);
      roundTo += currentItemGrams;
    }

  }

  console.log("rounded to " + roundTo);

}

roundUpBasedOnPackaging(287.5, [190, 290, 540, 1000]);
```

You can clearly see what I did: loop from highest to lowest and add if the value is not equal or over our initial value. But this of course won't work in the example I provided (for value 287,5 since it would be much better to just choose 290 instead of two times 190).

It would be nice if I could get the algorithm to choose bigger numbers first and then use smaller ones.. but if you can provide a solution where smaller ones are used as a priority - that would be useful also.

I reckon I'd need a combination of sums to solve this - all possible combinations?!, but it would probably get messy. I don't mind a bit of recursion though...

Also, I think the second condition (else if) in my code is not really optimal - I'm sure there is a case where this wouldn't work properly and even go over the given value.

Any tips appreciated. Will work on my second solution until then :)

Comment: Your problem statement is not fully clear. To achieve a given sum, do you want to first exhaust the large amounts and then smaller ones, or are you after the most accurate combination ? For instance, is 1140 rounded as 1000+190 or as 6x190 ?

Comment: The given sum would preferably be 1000+190 (higher numbers a priority) if possible.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "a priority", can you give a more rigorous statement so that we know without ambiguity what the expected solution is in a given case ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust the higher numbers should be used first if they can fit into the 'knapsack' as other people are referring to the problem.

Comment: @trainoasis: is exceeding the value allowed ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust exceeding or equaling the value is required

Answer (score 2):

If priority is given to the largest amounts and the given number may not be exceeded, the solution is straightforward.

Compute the number of times the largest amount fits (this is the quotient of the division) and deduce that.

Then repeat with the next largest,and so on.

```
1385: 1385/1000 = 1 => 385 remain
 385:  385/ 540 = 0 => 385 remain
 385:  385/ 290 = 1 =>  95 remain
  95:   95/ 190 = 0 => done.
```

Comment: That won't work in many cases, for example, if `S = 41`, and weights are `{20, 7}`. Your approach will result in 40 (20+20), while exact match exists (20+7+7+7).

Comment: @SashaSalauyou: you didn't read the first sentence nor the comments in the OP.

Comment: I did, but I still treat is as optimization problem (OP didn't discard that he needs nearest possible solution)

Comment: There's two points here indeed: 20+20 would stick to the rule that we use up the highest numbers first - but we would also need to add the lowest to that to get over the initial number. Whereas 20+7+7+7 is exactly the perfect solution for this case. I should probably define what is expected more clearly - will edit the question

Comment: @SashaSalauyou: I voted to close as the problem statement is ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

Seems this problem is similar to Knapsack problem, which is NP-hard, but if initial weights have big enough common divisor, solution can be found in acceptable time using dynamic approach.

Let `{K, N, M, ...}` - set of initial weights, `S` - number we need to round up.

1. Generate set of weights `W = {K, 2K, 3K,..., (|S/K| + 1)*K, N, 2N, ..., (|S/N| + 1)*N, M, ...}`, that will be used to fill up Knapsack. For repeating weights, select according to preference rule.
2. Build dynamic sorted set of combinations `D` where items (combinations) are ordered by summary weight, tracking minimal extra weight equal or greater than `S`, in `minExtra`. On other words, `minExtra` is the best weight found so far.

Algorithm:

```
D = {};
minExtra = +inf 
for each (e in W) {                 // take next element from W
    for each (c in D) {             // iterate over existing combinations in D
        nw = c.weight + e.weight;   // weight resulting of adding e
        if (nw < minExtra) {
            D.put(nw, c.add(e))     // assign to nw copy of c with e added
            if (nw >= S)
               minExtra = nw;
        }
    }
    if (e.weight < minExtra) {   
        D.put(new C(e))             // put combination of only item e
        if (e.weight >= S)
            minExtra = e.weight
    }
}
return D.get(minExtra)
```

`D.put()` should accept element of existing weight if combinations of more items are preferred, or discard otherwise.

Comment: generating weights can be a huge workload already don't you think? you mentioned 'according to preference rule' - but I don't have any - what did you mean by (|S/K| + 1)*K ? This W can be a huge array I believe?

Comment: @trainoasis for example, if S = 1000, K = 300, `(|S/K| + 1)*K` is `4*K`.

Comment: @trainoasis alternative is to traverse over all possible combinations, because this problem is NP-hard I believe.

Comment: @trainoasis I provided classical Knapsack dynamic solution applied to your case (GE instead of LE). Size of `W` depends on weights that can be generated by initial set, it can be small or large depending on input. For example, for `S = 500`, and initial weights `{100, 200, 300}`, `W` will consist of just 6 elements `{100*1, 200*1, 300*1, 200*2, 100*5, 300*2}`, because we are interesed in distinct weights only (e. g. `100*4` will be replaced by `200*2` if combinations of less elements are preferred).

Comment: Thank you, will dig into it when I have time and get back to you

Answer (score -1):

```
   Given number: 2875
   Expected result: 3020 (2x1000 + 1x540 + 1x290 + 1x190)
```

Expecting `10 × 290 = 2900` is closer. If that satisfies your rules.

If I'm right, this really makes me think of the [Knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem), although it's not exactly the same thing.

Edit. The algorithm you're looking if you need to have as many  big numbers as possible could look like something like this:

```
-> fit as many 1000s as you can, save in "a"
-> take the smallest next number that makes the sum greater, save result in "b"
-> use the biggest number smaller than the "smaller next number" in previous step, add them in "a" until you can't fit them anymore
-> take the smallest next number that makes the sum greater, save result in "c"
-> etc.
-> return the closest value you end up with
```

If it does not perform well enough to your liking (the results are not good enough), then you'll need to weigh those numbers according to some arbitrary values, and that, that is *exactly* a knapsack problem.

Comment: Maybe because it's not exactly a knapsack problem, as I've promptly corrected? I'd like to know too.

Comment: @Karl you are correct - 10x290 is closer. My rules were not that strictly defined, it's true - so your option is actually closer as you said. When I think about it - using the higher numbers first is actually preferable. I edited the question a bit also. And thanks for pointing out the Knapsack problem, will check it out

Comment: You probably forgot to add a link? Knapsack seems to be a similar problem yeah, but it's using less than or equal instead of greater than or equal. Would probably need a bit of a modification

Comment: Yeah, I hit enter and not shift enter. PEBKAC.

Comment: @trainoasis to switch from LE to GE, when you build dynamic matrix, on each step allow to add one more overweighting item to knapsack. Then just take set which weight is equal to `S` or next.

Comment: I have edited my response.

Since the downvoter has not justified himself, I'll just consider him as a useless troll trying to kick newcomers out of StackOverflow. Very immature.